# Support autovivified filehandle as arguments to Perl XS routine

Tags: perl, filehandle, xs

### Question

How can I support autovivified filehandle arguments in an XS function?

I'm XS-wrapping a C function which returns a file descriptor, and I'd like to present that file descriptor as a perl filehandle *argument* in the manner of [open()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).  E.g.,

```
myfunc(my $fh) or die "Error: $!";
do_something_with_fh($fh);
```

### What I've done so far

Right now I'm using a perl wrapper on top of the XS function:

```
# -- in perl
sub myfunc {
    my $fd = _myfunc();
    return open($_[0], '+<&=', $fd) if defined($fd);
}

/* -- in XS */
SysRet
_myfunc()
    CODE:
    RETVAL = some_c_function_returning_an_fd();

    OUTPUT:
    RETVAL
```

This works Just Fine (tm), but, again, I'd like to move the implementation entirely into XS.

So far I've tried `sv_2io` on an argument typemapped as `SV *`, but that throws an exception on undefined scalars.  I have not tried mapping the first argument to a `FILE *` or `PerlIO *` object, since I don't know how I'd "fdreopen" (if you will) those objects.

Comment: Maybe look at the autovivification module http://search.cpan.org/dist/autovivification/

Comment: I don't see any easy way of creating an `IO` object from the `PerlIO` returned by `PerlIO_fdopen`. The code behind Perl's `open` does it itself rather than calling a library function. Eventually, you'd call `sv_replace(fh, rv)` to move what you created into the argument (given `myfunc(SV* fh)`).

Comment: @Rob, that's a neat pragma, but it doesn't address the issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would keep the `myfunc()` wrapper in Perl, it works and shouldn't be a bottleneck.

Reimplementing `open()` is tricky and requires usage of undocumented/internal API. I think this is a pretty close implementation. `newGVgen()` and `do_openn()` is part of the public API but undocumented and [subject to change](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html#Undocumented-functions).

```
void
myfunc(sv)
    SV *sv
  PPCODE:
    {
        GV *gv = newGVgen("Mypackage");
        SV *rv = sv_2mortal(newRV_noinc((SV *)gv));
        SV *fd = sv_2mortal(newSViv(some_c_function_returning_an_fd()));

        if (!do_openn(gv, "+<&=", 4, FALSE, 0, 0, NULL, &fd, 1))
            croak("Could not fdopen descriptor: '%s'", Strerror(errno)); /* or XSRETURN_NO; */

        sv_setsv(sv, rv);
        SvSETMAGIC(sv);
        XSRETURN_YES;
    }
```